# Continually iterating through promises results in excessively deep stack

Tags: javascript, promise, circular-list

**LATER EDIT**

This question should be deleted, because the problem I'm reporting isn't even real.

There was no 'long chain of closures', that was me misunderstanding the google chrome watch window.

Any memory leak may be caused by the video elements not cleaning up properly. This is a different problem which has been addressed in other questions.

---

I am writing Javascript code to continually loop through a playlist. The items on the playlist are images (which display for 10 seconds) or videos.

Here's some code to do this (handling images or videos)

```
var IMAGE = 0;
var VIDEO = 1;

var mediaElements = [{
    url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bd/Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Self-Portrait_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/180px-Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Self-Portrait_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg',
    mediaType: IMAGE
}, {
    url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/English_Pok%C3%A9mon_logo.svg/269px-English_Pok%C3%A9mon_logo.svg.png',
    mediaType: IMAGE
}, {
    url: 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4',
    mediaType: VIDEO
}, {
    url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/34/Teuchitlan_scale_model_1_cropped.jpg/133px-Teuchitlan_scale_model_1_cropped.jpg',
    mediaType: IMAGE
}, {
    url:
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f7/Sugimoris025.png',
    mediaType: IMAGE
}


];

$(function () {

    function displayMediaFile(mediaFile) {
        $('#imageTarget').empty();
        if (mediaFile.mediaType === IMAGE) {
            $('#imageTarget').append($('<img />').attr('src', mediaFile.url));
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                window.setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
            });
        } else {
            var videoElement = $('<video></video>').attr('autoplay', '');
            var sourceElement = $('<source><source>')
                .attr('src', mediaFile.url)
                .attr('type', 'video/mp4')
                .appendTo(videoElement);
            videoElement = videoElement.appendTo('#imageTarget');
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                videoElement[0].onended = resolve;
            });
        }
    };


    function iterateThroughPlaylist(index) {
        if (index >= mediaElements.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        console.log('displaying image ' + index);
        displayMediaFile(mediaElements[index]).then(function () {
            iterateThroughPlaylist(index + 1);
        });
    }

    iterateThroughPlaylist(0);
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/355o93jr/2/) for a complete working example.

So the actual 'displayMediaFile' function returns a Promise. This promise resolves when the play is complete, and then we move on to the next image.

The problem is, it stops running after a while. I put a breakpoint in the `iterateThroughImages` method, then looked at the call stack. I could see an extremely long chain of closures.

Can I produce code with the same simplicity, but somehow avoid having the runtime keep the closures in memory?

Comment: Is the timeout always the same in real cases ? Why did you even consider promises here ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret I had tried simplifying the example, but I had obviously simplified it too much. I've modified my example to be closer to my actual problem, which includes both Pictures and Videos. Different media types have different end triggers, so I'm using promises as a common interface to both.

Comment: Did you look at my answer ? Because it can be adapted to you new question. It's still much simpler than promises (and also working)

Answer (score 2):

Promises don't seem to be the best solution here.

```
var imageUrls = [ url1, url2, url3, url4  ];
(function play(index){
    console.log('displaying image ' + index);
    var url = imageUrls[index];
    $('#imageTarget').empty().append($('<img />').attr('src', url));
    window.setTimeout(play, 2000, (index+1)%imageUrls.length);
})(0);
```

You could still use promises inside if you have other operations to chain but don't build an infinite chain of promises.

Side note: you don't really have to delete and recreate the `img` element, you could simply change its `src` property.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you would adapt this to different kinds of Media Types. The design goal I was working towards was having a clean separation between the display functionality and the iteration functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where promises are not the best solution. As long term stability is an issue it's better to make `iterateThroughPlaylist` run again more directly with :

- image: `window.setTimeout(iterateThroughPlaylist, 2000);`
- video: `videoElement[0].onended = iterateThroughPlaylist;`

As with promises, there's no recursion because `iterateThroughPlaylist` will be called in a later event turn in both cases.

```
$(function () {
    var mediaTypes = { 'IMAGE':0, 'VIDEO':1 },
        mediaElements = [
            ...
            ...
            ...
        ],
        index = -1;
    function displayMediaFile(index, fn) {
        var mediaFile = mediaElements[index];
        $('#imageTarget').empty();
        switch(mediaFile.mediaType) {
            case mediaTypes.IMAGE:
                $('#imageTarget').append($('<img/>').attr('src', mediaFile.url));
                window.setTimeout(fn, 2000);
            break;
            case mediaTypes.VIDEO:
                var videoElement = $('<video/>')
                    .attr('autoplay', '')
                    .append($('<source/>').attr({ 'src': mediaFile.url, 'type': 'video/mp4')})
                    .appendTo('#imageTarget');
                videoElement[0].onended = fn;
            break;
            default:
                //do nothing and let the sequence lapse, or
                //eg. window.setTimeout(fn, 2000); to keep trying
        }
    };
    function iterateThroughPlaylist() {
        index = (index + 1) % mediaElements.length;
        displayMediaFile(index, arguments.callee);
    }
    iterateThroughPlaylist();
});
```

**Notes**

- Passing `arguments.callee` as a callback is just a way of not hard-coding the function name `iterateThroughPlaylist`
- there are no inner functions within `displayMediaFile` or `iterateThroughPlaylist`, so only the outermost `$(function () {...}` forms a closure as expected.
- Containing everything in the `$(function () {...}` structure avoids the need to use the global namespace.
- `switch/case` will make it easier to add further media types if necessary.
- for even greater efficiency you could create the `<img>` and `<video>` elements up front and reuse them.